# How can I fix backtrace errors in a MediaWiki database?

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

While I attempted to create a database for my second wiki as a part of a wiki family I have been planning on, I have experienced various errors and access messages. One of these has to do with the user. Even though I have checked all the privileges I could see in my MySQL database manager, the backtrace shows that there are still missing permissions. Please give me information on how to fix these errors and explain what parts of the permissions are missing.

Backtrace:

```
#0 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(979): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->reportQueryError(string, integer, string, string, boolean)
#1 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1343): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->query(string, string)
#2 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1411): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->select(string, array, array, string, array, array)
#3 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/user/User.php(1287): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->selectRow(string, array, array, string, array)
#4 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/user/User.php(496): User->loadFromDatabase(integer)
#5 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/objectcache/WANObjectCache.php(892): User->{closure}(boolean, integer, array, NULL)
#6 [internal function]: WANObjectCache->{closure}(boolean, integer, array, NULL)
#7 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/objectcache/WANObjectCache.php(1012): call_user_func_array(Closure, array)
#8 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/objectcache/WANObjectCache.php(898): WANObjectCache->doGetWithSetCallback(string, integer, Closure, array, NULL)
#9 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/user/User.php(521): WANObjectCache->getWithSetCallback(string, integer, Closure, array)
#10 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/user/User.php(441): User->loadFromCache()
#11 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/user/User.php(405): User->loadFromId(integer)
#12 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/session/UserInfo.php(88): User->load()
#13 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/session/CookieSessionProvider.php(119): MediaWiki\Session\UserInfo::newFromId(string)
#14 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/session/SessionManager.php(487): MediaWiki\Session\CookieSessionProvider->provideSessionInfo(WebRequest)
#15 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/session/SessionManager.php(190): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager->getSessionInfoForRequest(WebRequest)
#16 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/WebRequest.php(735): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager->getSessionForRequest(WebRequest)
#17 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/session/SessionManager.php(129): WebRequest->getSession()
#18 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/Setup.php(762): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager::getGlobalSession()
#19 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/WebStart.php(114): require_once(string)
#20 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/index.php(40): require(string)
#21 {main}
```

Comment: You have not shared the error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix errors with database user in MediaWiki?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343438/how-to-fix-errors-with-database-user-in-mediawiki)